# To count the rows and its values in word docx by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, python-docx

I have a word docx which consist no of tables. Each table has different rows and columns name but among all one row name is same in all different table that is "test automation", It has the values of "yes or no" . Here my question is how can i count the total no of "test automation" Rows values like this "TOTAL NO OF TEST AUTOMATION:yes=200,no=100" I'm using python 3.6. Am new to python please help me. My sample code for the table extraction and specific column extraction.

Image of sample data: Sample data[image]

my code looks like this to extract the docx table

```
import pandas as pd
from docx.api import Document

document = Document('test_word.docx')
table = document.tables[0]

data = []

keys = None
for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    if i == 0:
        keys = tuple(text)
        continue
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)
    print (data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Is the Yes/No column always the fourth column? Or is one of the challenges figuring out which column to look in once you've located a test automation row?

Comment: Is it possible to track the row's and column's to identify it? You can assume that yes/no column is the 4th one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the essential logic you need to count Yes values for test automation. You'll need to deal with any Pandas manipulations you need:

```
from docx import Document

def table_test_automation(table):
    for row in table.rows:
        row_heading = row.cells[0].text
        if row_heading != 'Test automation':
            continue
        yes_no = row.cells[3].text
        return 1 if yes_no == 'Yes' else 0

    return 0


document = Document('test_word.docx')
yes_count = 0
for table in document.tables:
    yes_count += table_test_automation(table)
print(yes_count)
```

Comment: what does it mean? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arunbask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\read_table.py", line 17, in <module>
    yes_count += table_test_automation(table)
  File "C:\Users\arunbask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\read_table.py", line 5, in table_test_automation
    row_heading = row.cells[0].text
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'cells'

Comment: Oops, remove the `enumerate()` surrounding `table.rows` in line 4. I've fixed in code example.

Comment: Thanks @scanny. Works great!

Comment: I have two questions for you :) first one, If the "yes/no" is in different different columns then what will be solution? second one, I can read the "docx" from the python folder only, What should i do to read "docx" any of the folder in my machine?

Comment: @ArunBaskar I think those are best posted as separate questions. If you tag them with 'python-docx' I'll see them.

Comment: i posted the question please check it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723873/to-count-the-rows-values-which-has-no-column-in-docx-by-python