# To count the row's values in different tables which are presented in docx by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have a word docx which consist lots of table. so I'm getting trouble to go through all the table and counting some details. I need to automate those cases. Here my question is, First thing i need to read the table which has the header of "Test case details" then i need to count the "Test Type" row which has the "black box" testing value. Here i attached the word docx image for your concern. I need the output like "Total no of Black box test: 200". I'm using python 3.6, Please help me.

sample image of docx
[image]

sample code, i tried

```
from docx import Document

def table_test_automation(table):
    for row in table.rows:
        row_heading = row.cells[9].text
        if row_heading != 'Test Type':
            continue
        Black_box = row.cells[1].text
        return 1 if Black_box == 'Black Box' else 0

    return 0


document = Document('VRRPv3-PEGASUS.docx')
yes_count = 0
for table in document.tables:
    yes_count += table_test_automation(table)
print("Total No Of Black_box:",yes_count)
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you posted?

Comment: table has no column and i need to read only table which has the header of "test case details". this code giving only the output as zero

Comment: I don't see what you're saying. You said the table has no columns, but it seems quite apparent that this table has two columns (although the first row has the two columns merged). Are you asking how to detect a table that has the heading "Test Case Details"?

Comment: I have 300 tables in one docx file. There are different kinds of tables.  Among that i need to retrieve only this "test case details" table. After that i need to count total no of black box test. now you got it?

Comment: @scanny did you understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the contents of the first row is, so this might take some experimentation.

The place to start is by printing out the contents of the table heading cell:

```
table_heading_text = table.rows[0].cells[0].text
print(table_heading_text)
```

If that text were "Test Case Details", you can just test on that to qualify the table for further processing.

The thing that makes me suspicious is the disk icon. If that cell contains only an image, this approach isn't going to work.

Comment: that disk icon itself an image other than that all are text format only. Don't know why people giving task like this to me :)

Comment: Now you got it @scanny? I want my output will looks like this "Total no of black box testing:" 200.

Comment: I'm trying this code. Please help me @scanny                                                             from docx import Document

def table_test_automation(table):
    
    for row in table.rows:
        row_heading = row.cells[0].text
        if row_heading != 'Test case Details':
            continue
        Black_box = row.cells[1].text
        return 1 if Black_box == 'Black Box' else 0

    return 0
document = Document('VRRPv3-PEGASUS.docx')
yes_count = 0
for table in document.tables:
    yes_count += table_test_automation(table)
print("Total No Of Black_box:",yes_count)